# implementing exotic complex numbers to use with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i'm using python + numpy + scipy to do some convolution filtering over a complex-number array.

```
field = np.zeros((field_size, field_size), dtype=complex)
...
field = scipy.signal.convolve(field, kernel, 'same')
```

So, when i want to use a complex array in numpy all i need to do is pass the dtype=complex parameter.
For my research i need to implement two other types of complex numbers: dual (i*i=0) and double (i*i=1). It's not a big deal - i just take the python source code for complex numbers and change the multiplication function.
The problem: how do i make a numpy array of those exotic numeric types?

Comment: did you try using `dtype=your_exotic_complex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
from iComplex import SplitComplex as c_split
...
ctype = c_split
constructor = np.vectorize(ctype, otypes=[np.object])
field = constructor(np.zeros((field_size, field_size)))
```

That is the easy way to create numpy object array.
What about scipy.signal.convolve - it doesn't seem to work with my complex numbers and i had to make my own convolution and it works deadly slow. So now i am looking for ways to speed it up.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to create a new dtype for e.g. dual numbers. It is possible to do this with the following code:

```
dual_type = np.dtype([("a", np.float), ("b", np.float)])
dual_array = np.zeros((10,), dtype=dual_type)
```

**However** this is just a way of storing the data type, and doesn't tell numpy anything about the special algebra which it obeys.

You can partially achieve the desired effect by subclassing `numpy.ndarray` and overriding the relevant member functions, such as `__mul__` for multiply and so on. This should work fine for any python code, but I am fairly sure that any C or fortran-based routines (i.e. most of numpy and scipy) would multiply the numbers directly, rather than calling the `__mul__`. I suspect that `convolve` would fall into this basket, therefore it would not respect the rules which you define unless you wrote your own pure python version.

Comment: so, the only way is to write my own convolution which will be 100500 times slower than scipy's? =\

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Your code would be written in python, but it can still be built on the underlying fast operations which numpy provides. You just need to write your own __mul__ etc. to effeciently call numpy routines (which should be easy), then write your convolution routine to operate on arrays.

Comment: hmmm, so i DO have to write my own convolution rather than using scipy's? this is what frustrates me.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that this is the case. It might be worth your while considering using sage (www.sagemath.org). This is a very extensive python-based mathematics package (it actually includes numpy and scipy) and is more geared towards abstract mathematics so it may be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to turn things inside-out?  I mean instead of an array as the outer container holding small containers holding a couple floating point values as a complex number, turn that around so that your complex number is the outer container.  You'd have two arrays, one of plain floats as the real part, and another array as the imaginary part.  The basic super-fast convolver can do its job although you'd have to write code to use it four times, for all combinations of real/imaginary of the two factors.

In color image processing, I have often refactored my code from using arrays of RGB values to three arrays of scalar values, and found a good speed-up due to simpler convolutions and other operations working much faster on arrays of bytes or floats.

YMMV, since locality of the components of the complex (or color) can be important.

Comment: i don't think that complex numbers are similar to rgb pixels in this way. you cannot isolate real part from imaginary part. example: i*i=-1